# I don't have the permission to restore files, using Backups graphically

Tags: permissions, backup, restore

I've done a backup from the backups app in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Now, I want to restore those files in a different laptop, with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

- If I try to use the graphical way, I get the warning that Backups does not have permission to restore some files...

I can't find it now, but I remember reading an answer on this forum about a way to restore files from the terminal, when this happened.

- I've also tried `sudo duplicity restore file://<path_to_backup> /~`,
  however, I get `destination directory already exists. Will not overwrite`.

Comment: When I've run into those issues, I make a new directory, restore into that, then copy over.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--force`

```
sudo duplicity restore --force file://<path_to_backup> /~
```

Mind that this does not remove files on disk not restored from the backup so is kind of dangerous. (a backup should always restore to what it was and not aggregate files).

- In case you want the actual restore use `rm` to remove the destination. But what is the idea of `/~`? I would assume `~` or `.` or am absolute directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I've tried it, but I see two strange things: 1) the last backup date is strange (May 21, when I've backed up on the 23rd of June), 2) I also got several error messages of not being able to overwrite some existing files...

Comment: btw, thanks for calling my attention to /~ instead of ~. ;)